# How to insert data in PDo

Tags: php, mysql, insert, pdo

I use PDO and i can't insert some data:

use this code:

```
$sql  = 'INSERT INTO `releases` (id, artists, release, label, catalog, date, tracklist, type, status, vote, votes_count) ';
$sql .= 'VALUES (:id, :artists, :release, :label, :catalog, :date, :tracklist, :type, :status, :vote, :votes_count)';

$query = $this->db->prepare($sql);

$query->bindParam(':id', 0, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindParam(':artists', implode('|||', $data['artists']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':release', $data['release'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':label', $data['label'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':catalog', $data['catalog'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':date', $data['date'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':tracklist', $data['tracklist'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':type', $data['type'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':status', $data['status'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindParam(':vote', 0, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindParam(':votes_count', 0, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$query->execute();
```

but data don't inserted to database. all names checked and valid. id as AUTO_INCREMENT field.

if i use this code:
    $this->db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
    $sql  = 'INSERT INTO `releases` (artists, release, label, catalog, date, tracklist, type, status, vote, votes_count) ';
    $sql .= 'VALUES (:artists, :release, :label, :catalog, :date, :tracklist, :type, :status, :vote, :votes_count)';

```
$query = $this->db->prepare($sql);

$array = array(':artists'   => implode('|||', $data['artists']),
               ':release'   => $data['release'],
               ':label'     => $data['label'],
               ':catalog'   => $data['catalog'],
               ':date'      => $data['date'],
               ':tracklist' => $data['tracklist'],
               ':type'      => $data['type'],
               ':status'    => $data['status'],
               ':vote'      => 0,
               ':votes_count' => 0);

$query->execute($array);
```

i receive error:

**Warning**:  PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'release, label, catalog, date, tracklist, type, status, vote, votes_count) VALUE' at line 1 in **C:\Program Files\Wamp\www\forthcoming\application\controllers\release.php** on line **89**

Comment: PDO is a bit secretive about errors. Turn error reporting on first. See here for details: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: You could also check the values in PDO::errorCode() and PDO::errorInfo() after the statement has been executed to see what the error is. Personally, I always set the PDO error mode to exceptions. I find this gives me the best control as an exception is raised when any error occurs. I can then catch this and handle it accordingly depending on the application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`date` and `type` are [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html) in mySQL.

Surround the field names with backticks:

```
INSERT INTO `releases` (`id`, `artists`, `release`, `label`, `catalog`,
`date`, `tracklist`, `type`, `status`, `vote`, `votes_count`) ';
```

or rename them.

Answer (score 3):

if ID is an auto_increment, why specify it in your insert query. This is not needed and may be the reason you don't see your inserted line.

Comment: so i can write
$sql  = 'INSERT INTO releases (artists, release, label, catalog, date, tracklist, type, status, vote, votes_count) ';
$sql .= 'VALUES (:artists, :release, :label, :catalog, :date, :tracklist, :type, :status, :vote, :votes_count)';`
?

Answer (score 1):

`bindParam` uses reference semantics. I don't think you can use it on a constant, like you're doing with your `PDO::PARAM_INT` lines.

I never use `bindParam`, and I recommend that you use `bindValue` instead. Or better yet - Pass an associative array to `execute`.

Comment: PDO::bindParam() and PDO::bindValue() are for different things. PDO::bindParam() allows you to bind a variable to a placeholder. The variable can then change value before, or after, the statement is executed. This allows you to prepare a statement once and execute it many times, changing the variable values. PDO::bindValue() only allows you to bind a static value to a placeholder. Both are perfectly good and used for different things. The third argument to each method is a PDO constant (like PDO::PARAM_INT) that tells PDO what kind of value the bound variable or value contains.